# Needed Guidance in Calendar for a simple java form using swing package?

Tags: java, swing, calendar

I have created a Registration form using java swing package, For the purpose of adding Date of Birth in the form I have used the following code particularly to add a JFrame via Swing Package. Is there any alternative way to simplify the code.

```
JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Date of Birth");

l2.setBounds(200,160,100,20);
String day[] ={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30"};
String month[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
String year[] = {"2012","2011","2010","2009","2008","2007","2006","2005","2004","2003","2002","2001","2000","1999","1998","1997","1996","1995","1994","1993","1992","1991","1990","1989","1988","1987","1986","1985","1984","1983","1982","1981","1980","1979","1976","1975"};
JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox(day);
cb1.setBounds(450,160,50,20);
JComboBox cb2 = new JComboBox(month);
cb2.setBounds(500,160,50,20);
JComboBox cb3 = new JComboBox(year);
cb3.setBounds(550,160,60,20);
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you'll never need to support a year before 1975 or a different language or <strong>a month with 31 days</strong>?

Comment: Use a calendar component?  Use enums for month names?  Use layouts?  I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @PaulTomblin - thats the problem too i am manually entering the year, atleast my code should have 80 years from the present

Comment: @AndrewThompson - is there any method that i can use for my Jcombobox to simplify the code

Comment: Only 80 years?  My grandfather is older than that, can he not use your service?  And what happens if somebody puts February 30th, 1900?  I don't know about combo-boxes, but I'm pretty sure there are some built-in date spinners (but that would probably be by day).  You may need to do more work for this.  I'd start by passing the bounds of the allowed range as parameters to the setup method.

Comment: Use a calender widget instead. This avoids checks whether the date is valid. Oh yeah, ditch the `setBounds` calls as well and use a `LayoutManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source code for a calendar picker I wrote several years ago.  I'm not including all the dependencies like graphic files etc, but I'm pretty sure you can figure out what's missing and reproduce it.  I wrote it for a department in a company that closed down that department, so I doubt anybody is going to be claiming copyright on it.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15266/SmallCalendar.java

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15266/DateFormatInfo.java

Note that SmallCalendar includes a main so you can test it and see how it's meant to be called.  It's pretty good about Locales.